# Forked child processes does not exit

Tags: node.js, fork, child-process

I have a script downloading pdf files. These files come in batches of 5. So I thought of using fork to download 5 files simultaneously then when finished start the next 5. I made a small test file before jumping to full scale project. I found 2 problems

1. child process does not exit (it seem) after downloading
2. fork is not async. meaning I have to use some other method for waiting before sending next batch

main

```js
    const fork = require('child_process').fork;
    var url_s = ["https://www.responsibilityreports.com/HostedData/ResponsibilityReportArchive/a/NASDAQ_AAON_2020.pdf", "https://www.responsibilityreports.com/HostedData/ResponsibilityReportArchive/a/NASDAQ_AAON_2019.pdf"];
    var year_s = ["2020","2019"];
    name ='a';
    type = 'a';
    
    const ls = fork('a.js');
    
    ls.on('exit', (code)=>{
            console.log(`child_process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
    ls.on('close', (code)=>{
            console.log(`child_process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
    ls.on('message', (msg) => {
        ls.send([url_s[0],name,type,year_s[0]]);
        ls.send([url_s[1],name,type,year_s[1]]);
    });
```

child

```js
    const down_path = 'test/';
    const https = require('https');
    const fs = require('fs');
     
    process.on('message', async (arr) => {
        console.log("CHILD: url received from parent process", arr);
        url = arr[0];
        name = arr[1];
        type = arr[2];
        year = arr[3];
        await download(url,name,type,year);
    });
    
    process.send('Executed');
    
    async function download(url,name,type,year) {
        https.get(url, res => {
            const stream = fs.createWriteStream(down_path + name + '_' + type + '_' + year + '.pdf');
            res.pipe(stream);
            stream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('done : ' + year);
                stream.close();
            });
        });
    }
```

I tried to kill child processes manually using `process.kill()` and `process.exit()`,

```js
    stream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('done : ' + year);
        stream.close();
        process.exit()
    });
```

but it kills all the child processes, not the one I want.

Comment: You're only starting one child to handle all the downloads. Also, the child process doesn't exit because of `process.on('message')`: it doesn't know there won't be any more messages coming in, so it will just wait for more.

Comment: how do I start more childs? I am using a loop to go through the download links (which is not shown here). Thank you in advance @robertklep

Comment: The reason I am using 5 at a time is the website capping at about 300Kbps per download for some reason. But when download simultaneously each has a 300Kbps download speed. I tested this manually using chrome. I think it is something with my ISP not the website itself. @KJ

Comment: would using `const ls1 = fork('a.js');` and `const ls2 = fork('a.js');` correct to start multiple children? @robertklep

Comment: Thank you. But how to avoid using `process.on('message')` keeping the functionality?